# employ, employer, employee - can I generalize this pattern to (verb), (verb)er, (verb)ee?

Tags: grammaticality, morphology, derivational-morphology

As a non-native speaking programmer, I need a general pattern to name input and output variables of operations where the variables are of the same type and I noticed that employ, employer employee is a great pattern. Can I use this for any verb?

**Are the following correct?**

- merge, merger, mergee
  (the function is called merge, the one everything is merged into is called merger and the mergees are the ones that go into the merge)
- split, splitter, splitee (the function is "split", the original item is the "splitter" and the "splitees" are the results)
- connect, connector, connectee
- transfer, transferer, transferee
- approve, approver, approvee
- support, supporter, supportee
- manage, manager, managee

And so on.

If no, how do I decide when I can do this and when I can't?

Comment: *Can I use this for any verb?*. If your only concern is giving 'English-like' names to program entities, then knock yourself out and go right ahead.  In the previous sentence the expression *knock yourself out* is an idiom meaning, approximately, *fill your boots* or *please yourself*, it's not meant literally to suggest self-concussion.

Comment: The problem is that you’re trying to squeeze the often irregular, unruly and illogical English Language into the confines of a programmer’s logical, regular and precise world. Sorry, but it ain’t gonna work my friend!

Comment: No. [Heterogeneity in Word-formation Patterns: A Corpus-based Analysis ...
By Susanne Muehleisen](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3g_7oRyZi74C&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=ee+words+not+following+pattern&source=bl&ots=SEihDpG76x&sig=ACfU3U10G4J_L4JyOx_hTeBdcSYx0tLt1g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2i6SsxoXnAhWVTBUIHSuECykQ6AEwFnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=ee%20words%20not%20following%20pattern&f=false) is a 250-page study examining the patterns involved, the (numerous) exceptions, and new usages appearing over recent times. I obviously have to close-vote as 'too broad in scope'; a (or >1) dictionary is required.

Comment: ... Possibly the OED itself. Though 'noddee', to my surprise and delight, is given in Lexico. 'Festschriftee' is even rarer. 'Moneylendee' looks useful. 'Sneeree' contrived. (All these in Muehleisen.)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: My concern is if that style is "English-like" enough so that other people understand what I mean without additional explanation.

Comment: I'm a programmer myself. I spend _a lot_ of time thinking of good names for variables, using the most natural English I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, **no, you cannot use this for all verbs**.

The addition of *-er/-or* to indicate the person or item which performs the verb can be applied to most verbs. As @EdwinAshworth points out in the comments, there are some for which it sounds - at best - questionable ("rainer", "snower", for example), but it's generally a productive suffix which can be widely applied to verbs to indicate somebody/something which performs the verb. Edwin also found an interesting and relevant publication: [Combinatorial Restrictions of Agentive Suffixes in English and Serbian, by Vladimir Ž. Jovanović](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/298215233_COMBINATORIAL_RESTRICTIONS_OF_AGENTIVE_SUFFIXES_IN_ENGLISH_AND_SERBIAN) which discusses this among other things. It points out that -er/-or forms can sound strange if there's already an established noun (you wouldn't use *spyer/spier* in place of *spy*, for example). But generally speaking, if you need a noun for *somebody who verbs* and none appears to be established, *verb-er* or *verb-or* would probably be accepted by most people as a reasonable coinage.

But the addition of *-ee* to indicate the person/item the verb is *done to* isn't nearly so generalisable. Employee certainly isn't the only example (*trainee* and *interviewee*, for example, are widely used), but it can't be applied to most verbs.

When I say it can't be applied to most verbs, I mean that with most verbs it sounds unusual and would probably be considered an error by most people, especially (but not exclusively) in formal contexts. I would still expect most people (at least most native speakers of English) to understand your intention (at least roughly). In particular, *none* of the  *-ee* examples you gave sound natural to me (*perhaps* transferee, which I would understand as being the recipient of a transfer).

I'd also note that for the two examples where you've provided definitions, I wouldn't interpret them in the same way you have:

> **merge, merger, mergee** (the function is called merge, the one everything is merged into is called merger and the mergees are the ones that go into the merge)
>   **split, splitter, splitee** (the function is "split", the original item is the "splitter" and the "splitees" are the results)

for me, I would interpret the *merger* as being *the person/machine/etc that performs the merging*. It could perhaps in some contexts indicate the things which go into the merge, but I certainly wouldn't understand it as the result of the merge.

Likewise, the splitter *could* be the item which splits. But I'd be more likely to understand it as the person/object which causes something to split. I would only understand *splittee* as being *the thing which somebody/something caused to split*, and certainly not as the results of something being split.

In general, I'd sum up the relationship between *verb*, *verber*, and *verbee* as: a *verbee* gets *verbed* by the *verber*.

It's possible others may interpret them the same way you did, or another way altogether. But as I said above, neither of those examples sound at all natural to me with -ee so I would avoid using them regardless of what exactly you intend them to mean.

As for how you can tell which verbs you can do this with, unfortunately I don't believe there's any way other than checking a good dictionary to see if a particular form is recognised (or simply knowing from past experience, of course). *-ee* in particular is not a widely productive suffix, and I wouldn't recommend coining new words with it in serious contexts. It's not too unusual to hear it used innovatively for humorous effect, though.

Comment: Yes, to me a “splitter” refers to a tool for splitting logs of wood, and yet the proposal here is akin to calling the log of wood the “splitter”.

Comment: "Merger" is often used to mean a company or other organisation which is the *result* of merging two or more predecessors.

Comment: @RosieF I've always understood the merger in that context as being *the act of merging companies*, not the company that results from it. i.e. ExxonMobil is the result of the merger of Exxon and Mobil. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/merger) and [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/merger) both seem to define it in this way too.

Comment: At ResearchGate is to be found an article by Vladimir Ž. Jovanović
of the University of Niš on [combinatorial restrictions of agentive suffixes in English {and Serbian!}]( https://www.researchgate.net/publication/298215233_COMBINATORIAL_RESTRICTIONS_OF_AGENTIVE_SUFFIXES_IN_ENGLISH_AND_SERBIAN. Agent nouns such as 'pianoer', 'celloer', 'violiner', 'guitarer', 'celester, 'organer' and 'oboer' (not derived from verbs, of course) are blocked. I suspect 'rainer', 'telescoper', 'snower' etc are dubious.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth that's a great find, I'll edit something on that into the answer a little later (or feel free to do so yourself)

Comment: The problem with a dictionary is that as far as I know it only contains word forms that have already been used by someone. Maybe some verb forms are allowed but just have never been used by anyone, especially if the verb is only used in a very specific domain and not in everyday language.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Thanks for the link to the paper, it contains a great definition! "The suffix - EE of Latin and French origin is the only agentive suffix that belongs to Class I affixes 3 which change the stress pattern of the base. Even though the suffix- EE is primarily used to designate a person who undergoes a certain action, or presents an indirect object of the verb in the root, it also may have agentive implications, as in ateend-ee “someone who attends or is present”, returnee “someone who returned”, but surrender-ee is “someone to whom a surrender is made”."

Comment: @KonradHöffner these aren't verb forms, but yes it's broadly true that most dictionaries only have entries for words with some degree of established usage rather than anything that might be acceptable. But in this case, with -ee, you're talking about a relatively unproductive suffix, I'd argue that they're more or less the same thing. Assume it can't be used with any particular verb unless you have a reason to believe otherwise.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I understand "agent noun" to denote a noun which is derived from a verb V and which means "person who Vs" or "thing which Vs". Are nouns derived otherwise called agent nouns? We have "trumpeter", "bugler" and "drummer", but there's no "doing" for the term "agent" to refer to, so the term "agent noun" seems to be a misnomer.

Comment: @KonradHöffner And there's escapee, someone who's escaped from prison -- but that is from Fr. échappé, the *active* perfect participle of the *intransitive* verb échapper, hence the French word's meaning. The English word's being derived from the French one explains how come the English one has -ee. But that doesn't explain "attendee" or "standee", which were compounded in English from an English verb and -ee -- why -ee and not -er?

Comment: @Rosie F: It's a matter of which _precising definition_ you choose, as usual. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_noun) mentions the grey area. Note that it neatly avoids 'verb' in the definition.  [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agent%20noun) has: << Definition of **agent noun**
: a noun denoting the performer of an action (as writer, inspector, patron, hanger-on) >> (and 'patron' was here before 'patronise'). One would probably class 'executioner', 'probationer' and 'extortioner' as agent nouns, though the immediate derivation is from the 'action'-denoting noun.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [**productive**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productivity_(linguistics)) set of morphological constructions, so you can use it for new verbs and most English speakers will be able to understand it. However, it is very often the case that the pattern is not used for existing words. For example we say *student* not *teachee*. If you do use *-ee* it is likely to be interpreted as a humorous use of language, which may not be your intention. I would in general not recommend using *-ee* in new words in serious contexts. But if you are facing a [lacuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_gap) *-ee* may be a good derivational choice to fill the vocabulary gap, even in a serious context.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me a good heuristic on when to use it! I mostly need it for technical jargon so I think those are mostly new words where I can apply the pattern.